# stm32cubeide не могу вывести кириллицу нужна помощь Гуру

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: функция sprintf(str, "привет") кодируется в двухбайтовом формате.

```
str[0]  char    208 'Ð' 
str[1]  char    159 '\237'  
str[2]  char    209 'Ñ' 
str[3]  char    128 '\200'  
str[4]  char    208 'Ð' 
str[5]  char    184 '¸' 
str[6]  char    208 'Ð' 
str[7]  char    178 '²' 
str[8]  char    208 'Ð' 
str[9]  char    181 'µ' 
str[10] char    209 'Ñ' 
str[11] char    130 '\202'
```

Нужно сделать однобортный.

Пытался сделать следующие настройки.

1. Window--->Preferences--->General--->Workspace ---> ввел CP1251 и нажал apple and close
2. project ---> properties ---> Resourse ---> ввел cp1251 и нажал apple and close
3. Пересобрал проект ошибок и предупреждений не было.
4. ввел :

char str[32];
sprintf(str,"Привет");
Открыл в notepade в hex редакторе и увидел на слово "привет" следующие:

d0 9f d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b2 d0 b5 d1 82

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @zhilenkov - сохраните свои исходники в cp1251 или 866 (в зависимости от потребностей)

Comment: Как это сделать ? Расскажите более подробно.

Comment: @zhilenkov Ваш файл с исходным кодом в кодировке UTF-8 , если хотите сделать кодировку  cp1251 перекодируйте файл с исходным кодом в кодировку cp1251 или напишите напрямую кодировку cp1251 `sprintf(str, "\xEF\xF0\xE8\xE2\xE5\xF2")`